# Number of Output Partitions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

Suppose within an AWS Glue job, one sees the following output in the logs:

```
21/07/27 18:25:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (toPandas at /tmp/test.py:742) with 100000 output partitions
```

Does Spark dynamically set the number of output partitions? Is there any way to set the number of output partitions in advance for a particular job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try following method on your dataframe.

`repartition()` - when you want to increase a number of partition

`coalesce()` - when you want to decrease the number of parition.